# What is recommended way to push results from first monitor to second monitor in a dual screen/browser set up

Tags: node.js, sqlite, kiosk, multiple-monitors

I'm using Chrome on a dual screen monitor, for a Web-based POS application. First screen is the main screen while second is the Customer display.

What I thought was to make use of Node.JS and SQLite locally on the machine, so that the Main screen writes to this SQLite database. The second screen will then have to utilize Node.JS polling mechanism to look for updates in the SQLite database and display in the customer display.

Is this implementation okay? Or are there better ways to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Polling is a bad way for two servers to communicate.  Why not just use a socket.io connection between the two servers and you can just fire it a message anytime it should update its display.

Comment: The communication is essentially not a two server communication, because although the main client is connecting to a remote server, it is communicating to the other internet browser(secondary monitor) via local SQLite/Node.js only. The latency is local. So it's not two servers communicating, but rather a client just reflecting some values to another client from the same machine via a local server(Node.js).

Comment: I know that's what you're doing.  That doesn't mean that continuously polling a SQL database is still the right way to update a consumer-facing display.  You asked if there are better ways and I offered one.  It sounds like you are aren't really interested in other/better ways.  My point was you could communicate directly with the client that is displaying data if you wanted so it knew exactly when to update the display rather than having to guess or continuously poll.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood your earlier answer because you used the term server, sorry for that. You mean then that since Node.js is essentially still just polling the SQLite, it's not efficient or recommended. Sockets is a direct communication to the browser client. I have no experience with Sockets, but I might as well try that. thanks!

Comment: I would recommend the socket.io library.  It gives you a nice message passing layer that is easy to use.  You just send a message with optional data from one end of a connection to the other.